# layout unique id

Tags: android, android-xml

As [android official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#id) declare:

> An ID need **NOT** be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be
>   unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often
>   be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when
>   possible).

I need an example clarifying this.
P.S: I have no problem with unique ID, but i'm interested in NOT unique ID.

Comment: It would be better if down-voters present their ideas

Comment: I'm not sure what part is confusing. There are no requirements that an Id needs to be unique, i.e. you can have 2 views that have the same Id in your tree. That's the case when you have a list view for example. But whenever you `findViewById`, obv. if your sub-tree has duplicates Ids, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: So ID in andriod is like "class" in HTML that can be unique or not. right?

Answer (score 1):

**An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible).**

It means in single layout file, you should use unique id for each elements which you need reference somewhere else. See below example, if it help you to understand. You have to use different ID for different views in single layout file.

For example,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/tb_double_button"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to clarify this: "An ID need NOT be unique ...".

Comment: @alex I.e.: different layout files can have the **same** `android:id="@+id/view1"`